# ¿Como se puede reemplazar una opción de un selector que usa una librería de selectores múltiples?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Por defecto está seleccionado la opción "Todos". Si el usuario selecciona la opción "Todos", borra todas las que haya seleccionado antes y deja la que viene por defecto ("Todos"), pero necesito también que si el usuario selecciona otro mes borre la opción de todos y me deje colocar los meses gracias.

```js
$('.multiple').chosen({placeholder_text_multiple: 'Seleccione'});

$(document).on('change','#mes',function(){
  if($.inArray("todos", $(this).val()) > -1){
    $(this).chosen().val('todos').trigger("chosen:updated");
  }else{
  
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control multiple" multiple id="mes">
  <option value="todos" selected>Todos</option>
  <option value="enero">Enero</option>
  <option value="febrero">Febrero</option>
  <option value="marzo">Marzo</option>
  <option value="abril">Abril</option>
  <option value="mayo">Mayo</option>
  <option value="junio">Junio</option>
  <option value="julio">Julio</option>
  <option value="agosto">Agosto</option>
  <option value="septiembre">Septiembre</option>
  <option value="octubre">Octubre</option>
  <option value="noviembre">Noviembre</option>
  <option value="diciembre">Diciembre</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas verificar que valor fue seleccionado con `selected`.  Algo asi:

```js
$('.multiple').chosen({placeholder_text_multiple: 'Seleccione'});

$(document).on('change','#mes',function(evt, params){
  var x = $(this).val();
  if($.inArray("todos", $(this).val()) > -1){
    if(params.selected == 'todos') {
     $(this).chosen().val('todos').trigger("chosen:updated");
    } else {
     $(this).chosen().val(params.selected).trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
  }else{
  
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control multiple" multiple id="mes">
  <option value="todos" selected>Todos</option>
  <option value="enero">Enero</option>
  <option value="febrero">Febrero</option>
  <option value="marzo">Marzo</option>
  <option value="abril">Abril</option>
  <option value="mayo">Mayo</option>
  <option value="junio">Junio</option>
  <option value="julio">Julio</option>
  <option value="agosto">Agosto</option>
  <option value="septiembre">Septiembre</option>
  <option value="octubre">Octubre</option>
  <option value="noviembre">Noviembre</option>
  <option value="diciembre">Diciembre</option>
</select>
```

Puedes encontrar mas informacion en la documentacion aqui: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvió mucho.